# How to get the data of an embedded document inside a word document in Java

Tags: java, docx4j, aspose.words

I am using Aspose library node collection to read a Word document node by node, but embedded documents are being identified as node of type shape. How can i get the data inside those documents. Is there any way to achieve this using Aspose words or any other library.

Answer (score 1):

Embedded objects in Aspose.Words Document Object Model are represented by Shape nodes with [Shape.getOleFormat()](https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/shape/#getOleFormat) property set. You can check whether `OleFormat` property is not null to identify embedded OLE objects.
You can learn more about working with OLE objects from this article:
https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/working-with-ole-objects/